# I lose control Android's Webview when resuming the application

Tags: android, flash, webview, onresume

basically, what am doing is that am running a flash file (playing music) in the background of the app using webview, and when I want to stop the music , I just load "about:blank"

I want to keep the flash file running (music) when my app gets paused (which works fine so far) the problem is when the app resumes, pressing on pause button launches a new webview instead of changing the link in the previous one and the sound doesn't stop

the only solution I found was to kill the process and restart the app, but that's not practical, any idea of how to still be able to use the same webview when resuming the app ?

Update: guess I wasn't clear enough, I have a webview widget stated as "gone" , I only need the audio form the flash file I'm running in the webview so the "play" button loads a URL that contains the flash file (so the user only hears music, and doesn't notice that I'm using a webview), when I press the back/home button the music doesn't stop (I like it that way) but when I go back and press on play again it loads another url in a new page, you get double music

Comment: What is "pressing on pause button"? What is "launches a new webview"? Widgets are not "launched" in Android application development.

Comment: I added some clarification, hopefully it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few possible causes for this. One is simply that multiple instances of your activity are being created. Assuming you don't want this, add `android:launchMode="singleTask"` or `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` to your main `<activity>` in AndroidManifest.xml. More info here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode

If that doesn't help, another possibility is that your application is creating a new instance of the WebView -- either because the relevant code is in the wrong place (e.g. `onStart()`), or because the app has actually been destroyed and re-created by Android rather than paused and resumed -- and the old WebView thread is still hanging around for some reason. More information (such as code samples) would be helpful in identifying the problem, if that's the case.

Comment: This is on a slightly different subject, but depending on what you want, it may be better to call the WebView's `.onPause` and `.onResume` methods to pause and resume the music, instead of loading a different page.

Comment: I solved the issue by stopping when back button is pressed [onStop] so the user have to press on the home button if he wanna keep the music playing
but I didn't know there was onPause and onResume for the WebView :D
thanx a lot

Comment: No problem. You can also call `webView.destroy()` in your onDestroy() (or similar) if you want to ensure that Flash doesn't hang around hogging resources after people exit your application, by the way.

Comment: Note that the WebView doesn't support .onPause or .onResume in Android 1.5 and possibly 1.6 (though since they don't support Flash anyway, it doesn't matter in this case). Weirdly, the official Android Developers reference lists the methods as having been introduced in API level 11, but they've worked on every Android 2.2 device I've tried them on, and iirc on Android 2.1 as well. (??)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about this solution but at least you should try this once

```
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    activityTermsAndConditionBinding.webView.releasePointerCapture();
    activityTermsAndConditionBinding.webView.invalidate();
}
```